# How to apply fisheye effect to an image using css "background-image: url()"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an image in css like this:

```
background-image: url(https://imgur.com/lTpbsD4);
```

I am trying to apply a 'fisheye' effect to this image, so it can look like this:

https://support.usa.canon.com/library/attachments/ServiceWareImages/LDImages/SolutionAnswer/General_Digital_Camera/fisheye%20example.jpg

I found this codepen that accomplished something similar, though not quite what I have in mind. I want to just distort the image, but this codepen only works on hover, and does not use the css 'background-image()'

https://codepen.io/jOlga/pen/KyQMQW

How would I go to accomplish this using either css or js?

Comment: This answer may assist... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467496/1533592

Comment: What's stopping you from replacing the image url, placing the cursor exactly where you want it and making a screen capture? Save it as a static image, without the JS for making the effect dynamic, if that's all you need.

Comment: @tao the issue is I am trying to make a rotating earth, using css animations for it. The earth itself rotates by using a map, but it just looks very flat because it literally is flat. By using a fisheye effect I can make it appear to be round. Because it is something that is constantly changing, a screencapture wont do the trick

Comment: In that case you have an XY problem. The codepen you linked won't help, unless you have a way of detecting every possible change in the map (which, in my estimation creates a bigger problem than having a fisheye effect). You're better off using [fisheye.js](http://ericleong.me/fisheye.js/) which is capable of creating a permanent distortion of a specified page area.